# MODAL component in bootstrap acting really weird

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

I am having a quite peculiar problem with bootstrap's modal. It has been functioning normally until I decided that only some parts of my webpage should be called when the user is logged out. So I added these lines of php code :

```
<div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="tab-1">

                <!--FIRST ADDITION : THE IF CLAUSE -->
                <?php
                 if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"]) {
                include '2AversPA.php';
                 }
                ?>


            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-2">

                <!--SECOND ADDITION : THE IF CLAUSE -->
               <?php
                 if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"]) {
                include 'PAvers2A.php';
                 }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="tab-3">
                <p>Content for tab 3.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now, what is extremely weird is that. If I add the first "if" in the TAB1 and directly include 'PAvers2A.php' in TAB2 (ie without the second if clause), the modal works normally. The same goes if I add the "if" in the TAB2 and directly include '2AversPA.php' in TAB1.

BUT, if I add the two if clauses together (which is what I want) the modal just doesn't show up. The button still works and calls the element #MyModal but the dialog box just won't appear.

Can anyone help me solve this mystery?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Perhaps your includes contain duplicate ID's or conflicting scripts? Like trying to define the same function twice for example.

Comment: Yes, my console says :
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6

Comment: Just to clarify : I do call jquery.min.js in index.php and in 'PAvers2a.php" and '2AversPA.php'